# Excel time conversion

Tags: excel

I have a simple question concerning excel.

I have the hour of the day from `100` to `2400`, I'm trying to convert these to `01:00` to `24:00`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following formula

```
= (FLOOR(A1;100) + MOD(A1;100)*10/6)/2400
```

together with any number format of category "time" (assuming cell `A1` contains your value).

Comment: Thanks, but when I plug this formula with the value of 100 (my first value), I get 0.0416. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1106522 You have to choose an appropriate number format (Right click->Format Cells->Number->Time)

Comment: Thank you everyone! Figured this out with the help of that formula!

Answer (score 1):

```
=FIELD/2400
```

and formating as Time is maybe easyer and should bring the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in excel HOUR(value) where the value is a number between 0 an 23. And MINUTE(value) where value is a number between 0 and 59. Can you use this?